# RecyclerGridView under ScrollView

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am making a layout like below

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/l_out
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

              <-Some view here.....->
       </LinearLayout>
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/similar_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now problem is that I don't know the height of `l_out`. When the height of `l_out` is more, `RecyclerView` becomes hide and also some part of `l_out` becomes hide and `RecyclerView` does not work in `ScrollView`. How can I achieve my above layout do vertical scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
<ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/id_scroll">
          <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/similar_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: what is 'android:layout_below="@+id/id_scroll'

Comment: Have you reached your goal?

Comment: I placed the scroll view under one layout so that why i'm gave the scroll view as below of that layout so i used like that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have achieved my goal to make customGrid in scrollView